# How to convert int into Byte Array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in which there is one column named:

> 'eZip' (varbinary(5), null).

Now I am adding value from a web form like this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@eZip", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(txtZip.Text.ToString()));
```

Its working but instead of putting a valid zip code, it is inserting this into my column:

```
<Binary data>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you say that it's inserting that into your column?

Comment: If you're storing zip codes in a database, make the column `char` or `varchar`. Converting a zip code to an `int` is a bad idea in the first place, and then converting the `int` to binary is another bad idea.

Comment: @Adam: I checked it. My SP are in MSSQL 2008.

Comment: @Musi: so what should be the best Datatype for Zip in MSSQL 2008?

Comment: @Mayank: The best type for a zipcode in *any* RDBMS is a string type, either `char` or `varchar`. If you're only going to be handling US zip codes, `char(5)` (or `char(10)` if you want to handle the hyphen+4) would be the best choice.

Comment: @Mayank: I was really asking *how* you checked it. If you just looked at the data in Management Studio, then it will always show "Binary Data" for a `binary` or `varbinary` field.

Comment: @Adam: Oh, I clicked on edit top 200 rows and passed my info as a criteria into it.

Comment: @Mayank: Then that's why; SSMS does not allow you to view or edit binary data in that way, which is why it just displays "Binary Data". You need to change the data type if at all possible, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong per-se.  if you define the field as varbinary you will always see "Binary Data" in SQL Server's management tools, regardless of the data.

Are you sure you don't want just `CHAR(n)` OR `VARCHAR(n)`  for the zip code?

Comment: Zip codes are not integers, they're alphanumeric data that (in the US) only consist either of five numeric digits or nine numeric digits and a hyphen.

Comment: so what should be the best Datatype for Zip in MSSQL 2008?

Comment: @Adam You are correct, I will edit to specify Char or Varchar

Comment: @Mayank The most comprehensive zip code format in the US is the "Zip + 4" format, which is nnnnn-xxxx format.  So VARCHAR(10) would probably suffice, because it can hold the 5-digit or 9-digit versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the data type of that column, all you need to do is convert the value when you get the data back out.  As recommended by others, you should at least change your code to assume that the five bytes are characters, not integers.

Insert the value:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@eZip", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtZip.Text.ToString());
```

Retrieve the value in SSMS tools:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [eZip]) AS [eZip] FROM @zip_table;
```

Retrieve the value from a `DataRow dr` in C#:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dr["eZip"]);
```

If you can change the column to a CHAR(5) or VARCHAR(5), then no conversion will be necessary.